# How to connect VM and Host for l2fwd?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, dpdk

I am working on l2fwd application with DPDK. I have taken an Ubuntu 16.04 as the Host system that initiates the packet generator and the Ubuntu 16.04 VM that initiates the l2fwd application to analyze the packets that are forwarded.

I have installed DPDK and Pktgen in the corresponding machines, but I am not sure how to establish a connection between Host and VM so that my host can transfer the packets to VM. Should I go with a Host only network? I wasn't able to find much references.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the DPDK l2fwd user guide, [virtual function setup instructions](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides-16.04/sample_app_ug/l2_forward_real_virtual.html#virtual-function-setup-instructions).

Basically, the easiest way would be to either pass through your whole NIC to the VM or setup a virtual function (VF) on your NIC and pass through the configured virtual function.

Virtual function setup is different from driver to driver. For example, for ixgbe we pass arguments to kernel module, i.e.:

```
modprobe ixgbe max_vfs=2,2
```

The next steps are:

- unbind kernel NIC driver from NIC/VF
- bind the NIC/VF to vfio-pci driver
- pass the device to the VM with argument `-device vfio-pci,host=...`

Please find more information here:

http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/10G_NIC_performance:_VFIO_vs_virtio